# How would I be able to display the next article in sequence on click php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have added a news article which is saved in my mysql database onto my home screen. I am planning to use the arrows to display the next/previous article in sequence on click. How would I achieve this?

```
 <?php
 function custom_echo($x, $length)
 {
   if(strlen($x)<=$length)
   {
     echo $x;
   }
   else
   {
     $y=substr($x,0,$length) . '...';
     echo $y;
   }
 }
      $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM articles');
      $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      for ($i=0; $i < 1; $i++) { 
        echo '<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 height-news22">';
        echo '<h2 class="ashu">Latest News</h2>';
        echo '<br>'.'<p class="news-title78">'.$results[$i]['headline'].'<br>'.'<     /p>';
        echo '<img class="news-img33" src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(      $results[$i]['logo'] ).'"/>';
        echo '<p class="news-time">'.$results[$i]['dateTime'].'<br>'.'</p>'.'<p      class="news-body6">';
        custom_echo ($results[$i]['text'], 190);
        echo '</p>'.'<br>'.'<a href="news.php">'.'<button id="solo-buttons67">     Read More</button>'.'</a>';
        echo '<i id="arrow20" class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-1x"></i>'.'<i      id="arrow21" class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-1x"></i>'.'</div>';
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: you need jquery / ajax to do it without page reloading, or you reload again and again with new data

Comment: if you want to reload page, can you please show url of the page?